# handlebarjs block helper function (simple odd even attribute to add on each row of array) with requirejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js, javascript-framework

I included handlebarjs on my requirejs backbone app and I wanted to implement a row class helper definition (odd|even) on templates,

I'm trying to 'port' the native handlebar helper to a module based(requirejs): 
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers

with handlebarjs plugin for requirejs:
https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin

Here is the one i got so far **oddevenhelper.js**:

```
define(['handlebars'], function ( Handlebars ){
  function oddevenhelper(array, even, odd, fn, elseFn) {
      if (array && array.length > 0) {
        var buffer = "";
        for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++) {
            var item = array[i];

            // we'll just put the appropriate stripe class name onto the item for now
            item.stripeClass = (i % 2 == 0 ? even : odd);

            // show the inside of the block
            buffer += fn(item);
        }

        // return the finished buffer
        return buffer;
      } else {
        return elseFn();
      }
  };

  Handlebars.registerHelper( 'oddevenhelper', oddevenhelper );
  return oddevenhelper;
});
```

and this is my sample template:

```
<div class="orderssummary-list">
        {{#oddevenhelper orderssummary "even" "odd"}}
            <div class="ordersummary-list-item {{stripeClass}}">
                <a class="addone"><i class="icon-chevron-up icon-white"></i></a>
                <a class="minusone"><i class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></i></a>
                <div class="item-quantity">{{quantity}}x</div><div class="item-name">{{item_name}}</div> {{total}}
                <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
        {{/oddevenhelper}}
    </div>
```

The helper runs, but handlebar throws error on, i guess on the 3rd  or 4th parameter which i declared on the template to be undefined or none at all.

Am i missing something on this? Or i just let the context(orderssummary) to be redefined to include row classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hbs helpers are defined exactly as regular Handlebars helpers: they receive the template and inverse functions in the options hash, not as regular arguments. Your function should look like

```
function oddevenhelper(array, even, odd, options)
    var fn = options.fn,
        elseFn = options.inverse;

    ...
}
```

and a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/snZHu/

Comment: thanks again, i understand now how handlebar block helpers pass functions and data, and I edit your answer with added a oddevenhelper.js requirejs module, for those anyone interested